# MySQLi cannot connect to db, but MySQL can

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Config.php :**

```
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1:1433");
define("DB_USER", "****");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "****");
define("DB_DATABASE", "name");
```

for some odd reason i keep on getting error:

> mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:1433' (3) in filelocation/file.php on line X

line X = `$this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);`

the strange thing is that i also have an old mysql api running,

```
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

which connects to the db without any problems whatsoever.
note, that my MySQLi api was working and operational. This issue has only come to my notice since a week or two ago.

### Question

---

Do I need to update my apache to run mySQLi again?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Also, have you checked in `phpinfo()` to see if you have mysqli?

Comment: did you try `DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1` without the port number?

Comment: @b0s3, yes i have. I just get the same error but then to host '12.0.0.1'.

Comment: did u try using `localhost` instead of the ip and the port number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your port number in separate constant

```
define("DB_HOST", "127.0.0.1");
define("DB_USER", "****");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "****");
define("DB_DATABASE", "name");
define("DB_PORT", 1433);
```

And connect your database using  parameter

```
new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE,DB_PORT);
```

Comment: yes, that did the trick. Strange though, since it used to work... msqli update perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", "port number");
```